# Can I install a .vmlinuz-<version>.hmac for an installed kernel after the fact?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

I installed a kernel from elrepo on my asus ux501jw, centos7 os. I have tried the 4.5.0 and the 4.4.6 versions. Both of them do not install the hmac file /boot/.vmlinuz-.hmac file. Concequently the bios (efi) will not load that kernel. Is there a way to generate the hmac file for a package provided kernel?